# node.js internal message server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am pretty new to node.js. I am working on an app able to display NFC content on a webpage. I am using nfc-pcsp package (https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc), I can easily read data on server side. Now I just would like to display the data in the webpage, but I am stuck on the logic. Here is a part of my server code:

```
// ### launch server for client
var http = require('http');
var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname+'/custom.html');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
res.end(html);
});
server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
//######

 //#launch NFC routine ######
const nfc = new NFC(); // const nfc = new NFC(minilogger); // optionally you can pass logger to see internal debug logs

let readers = [];

nfc.on('reader', async reader => {

pretty.info(`device attached`, { reader: reader.name }); 

// the event is correctly displayed in the console. How to update html here?


readers.push(reader);


nfc.on('error', err => {

pretty.error(`an error occurred`, err);

});
```

It seems to me that I need a res object to update the html page, but as I do not get any request from client, how do I update the page just based on the callback from NFC module reader? Hope my question is clear. 
Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the express API
command with npm CLI : npm install --save express at your root project folder in your terminal
Then, you will be able to create a route in Get, Post, Put or Delete.
Next, In your client side you will be able to call this route by a get, post or whatever with a promise, ajax request whatever you want :)
Just understand that in order to receive or send data to your server, you need an url and with Express, you can create your own url.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

Don't hesitate to have a look on this API, and i'm pretty sure you will find the answer to your question on your own :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It means that on client side I need to constantly request the server to check if an nfc event has been triggered? It seems very heavy, no?

Comment: How would u communicate with the server if u don't request it. And yes you have to request your server. That's one of the reasons why express is so good :) u can mark ur question as resolve if u want it :)